# Problem reassigning value of a vector index based on value of another vector

Tags: r, indexing

I am trying to make a vector of prediction values. The commands for this are basic, but continue to throw up the same error. Why does following code leave "ww" still filled with  1's?

```
pp<-runif(100)
ww<-rep(1,100)
ww[pp>.5]=1
```

Comment: Because you created 'ww' as a vector of 1 and then it is replacing by 1.  So, it is not changing the values

Comment: Do you want to fill 'ww' with the values of 'pp'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP constructed the vector 'ww' as a vector of 1s.  Then, in the third line, created a logical vector with `pp` and replace the 1s in ww again with 1.  If the intention is to replace those values with 'pp', then either use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(pp > .5, pp, ww)
```

Or use the logical vector on both sides of assignment

```
ww[pp > 0.5] <- pp[pp > 0.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

rep fills ww with 100 "1"s.

Comment: Please give more details in your answer